# php prepared statement save result to array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to save the result of a php prepared statement into an array and then write it out (echo)

```
  <?php

require_once "DBinit.php";

$vpisna=$_POST['vpisna'];

$dbh = DBInit::getInstance();



$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM studenti");


$stmt->bindValue(':id_student', $id_student);
$stmt->bindValue(':ime', $ime);
$stmt->bindValue(':priimek', $priimek);
$stmt->bindValue(':naslov', $naslov);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':vpisna', $vpisna);
$stmt->bindValue(':geslo', $geslo);
$stmt->bindValue(':status', $status);

$stmt->execute();


        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        //$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM studenti");

        echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>
        <tr>
        <th> Št.</th>
        <th>Ime</th>
        <th>Priimek</th>
        <th>Naslov</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Vpisna številka</th>
        <th>Geslo</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['id_student'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['ime'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['priimek'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['naslov'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['vpisna'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['geslo'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";

          echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";


?>
```

Thank you for helping.

This should write out (into browser) a list of students with their info.

I couldnt figure out how to save stmt result into an array to read from it with $row.

Comment: you seem to be mixing PDO and mysqli

Comment: You're also binding values to a statement with no placeholders.

Comment: PDO has a `fetchAll` method ~ `PDOStatement::fetchAll` - use that

Comment: The solution has to be in PDO, the original was in mysqli thats why it is mixed up.

Comment: What do I need to change here :

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

because it has to be in PDO

Answer (score 0):

At first you must insert new row with a INSERT statement...

```
$row = [
    'ime' => 'Bob',
    'email' => 'bob@example.com'
];
$sql = "INSERT INTO studenti SET ime=:ime, email=:email";
$dbh->prepare($sql)->execute($row);
```

... then you can select and output all rows:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM studenti');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "</td>";
    // ...
    echo "</tr>";
}
```